How to write the correct comment to receive request body block with no param definition
Trying to receive this

but i get this:

My comment for handler:
// @Summary      Проверка checkProof
// @Description  **Проверка checkProof**
// @Tags         TONProof
// @Accept       json
// @Produce      json
// @Param        Request body datatype.TonProof true "Данные checkProof"
// @Success      200  {object}  ProofResponse
// @Failure      400  {object}  ErrMessage
// @Failure      500  "Internal Server Error"
// @Router       /ton-proof/checkProof [post]
func (h *handler) ProofHandler(c echo.Context) error {...}

Expecting no parameters comment & req body block.
I know what problem is wrong yaml struct, but i dont get why
